# Iterate over an existing map against a list of tuples scala

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a list of tuples that I must change the values for in a map that contains those tuples. So if I have a list such as `List((0,2), (0,3))` with a map that looks like this: `Map((0,2) => List(1,2,3), (0,3) => List(1,2))`, I need to access the matching map tuples with the tuples listed in the list, then remove a number from the mapping.

So in the example above, if I wanted to remove `2` from the mapping, I would get `Map((0,2) => List(1,3), (0,3) => List(1))`.

Design wise, I was thinking of pattern matching the map, but I've read some answers that said that may not be the best way. The tough part for me is that it has to be immutable, so I was thinking of pattern matching the list, getting the map value, change the value, then recreate the map and recursively call the function again. What do you think of this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way to remove `2` from your `Map`:

```
val newMap = oldMap.mapValues(list => list.filter(_ != 2))
```

Or more generally:

```
def filterInMap(element: Int, oldMap: Map[(Int,Int),List[Int]]) = 
    oldMap.mapValues(list => list.filter(_ != element))
```

This way there's no need to mutate anything at all. `mapValues` transforms just the values of your `Map` and returns a copy of the original without mutating it at all. `filter` then gets the job done by only allowing elements that don't match the element we would like to remove.

Bonus: even more generally:

```
def filterInMap[A](element: A, oldMap: Map[(A,A),List[A]]) = 
    oldMap.mapValues(list => list.filter(_ != element))
```